# Flex content in Bootstrap 5 tabs not hiding after changing tab?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, leaflet, bootstrap-5

[Bootstrap 5 tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior) has a Leaflet map which we want to fill all remaining space when selected. We got this working but now when changing tabs the area of the 1st won't go away.

We think it might be due to the ".tab-content > .tab-pane { <strike>display: none;</strike> }" property in CSS not being used or overridden as indicated by the strikethrough, but we don't know how to address this.

Simplified example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> 
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs d-flex" id="myTab">
  <li class="nav-item"><button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button">Map</button></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><button class="nav-link" id="table-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button">other tab</button></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="mappanel">
    <div id="mapid"></div>
      <script>var myMap = L.map("mapid");
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',}).addTo(myMap);
      myMap.setView([20.210183, -87.460003], 20);</script>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">other tab content</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body, #mappanel {  margin: 0px; height: 100%;}
body { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;}
#mappanel {flex: 1 1; order: 2; display: flex;}
#mapid, .tab-content  {flex: 1;}
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two mistakes

1. first tab-pane must be id="home" not id="mappanel"
2. if you need mappanel you have to use additional div inside tab-pane.
   see below

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> 
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs d-flex" id="myTab">
  <li class="nav-item"><button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button">Map</button></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><button class="nav-link" id="table-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button">other tab</button></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
     <div id="mappanel">    
        <div id="mapid"></div>
          <script>var myMap = L.map("mapid");
          L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',}).addTo(myMap);
          myMap.setView([20.210183, -87.460003], 20);</script>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">other tab content</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
html, body, #mappanel {  margin: 0px; height: 100%;}
body { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;}
#mappanel {flex: 1 1; order: 2; display: flex;}
#mapid, .tab-content  {flex: 1;}
</style>
```